# MVC id Value always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new in ASP.NET MVC. One of my first task I would like to do is passing a parameter to the `HomeController`.

To accomplish this I modified default `Index` method to:

```
public string Index(string strParam)
{
    return "Param: " + strParam;
}
```

I also pass my parameter via url as:

```
https://localhost:44308/home/index/test
```

but the parameter `strParam` is always null. How can I pass some parameters to my method using url?

My route config is default:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should name the parameter in the `Index` method `id`, as per the route definition. Otherwise, if you don't want to change it, add an `HttpGet` attribute such as:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("[action]/{strParam}")
```

Comment: It was a good idea to change the name of parameter in the method and it works but as u said it is possible to reach goal in other way. Where can I add 'HttpGet' attribute? Because When I am trying to add it above my method I got an error "HttpGetAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments". My project is .Net Framework.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was ASP.NET Core! I updated the response!

Comment: As you suggested I modified method and now it looks like `[HttpGet] [Route("home/index/{strParam}")] public string Index(string strParam)` but unfortunately it still doesnt work.

Comment: Can you try, just for debugging, to comment out the route definition in RegisterRoutes?

Comment: When I comment out the route definition I just have "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" and nothing works.

Comment: I have learned few things and have solved this problem. It didn't work just because I didn't have the `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` method in my `RegisterRoutes`. Now it seems to work perfectly. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, in your route its defined as `id`. If you name your paramater as such, it will also work.

```
public string Index(string id)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to pass it using query string 
for eg. 
https://localhost:44308/home/index?strParam=test.

sharing you snap please have a look 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

then try the following:

```
 [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class TestController : Controller
  {       
    [HttpGet("{value}")]
    [Route("/Test/Index")]
    public string Index(string value)
    {
        return "Hello " + value;
    }
```

in my startup -> Configure goes below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
   name: "default1",
   pattern: "{controller}/{action}");
});
```

http://localhost:5001/test/index/World

Output: Hello World

Answer (score -1):

have you try the following:

```
  [HttpGet("{strParam}")]
  [Route("/Home/Index")]

  public string Index(string strParam)
```

Comment: I think it a properly solution but I have an error "HttpGetAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments".

Comment: check your map route

Comment: @Don2: did any of this helped you?